# ServiceStack Session ID in URL

Tags: c#, .net, http, servicestack

Good day, I am not that familiar with this topic so excuse me if it's not explained in the best way.
I am using ServiceStack as my backend API and enabled "AllowSessionIdsInHttpParams = true". I am passing the ss-id via my url. I noticed that I can copy that ss-id and use in different clients (browser).
Should the ss-id not be validated against the user agent / client and only be validate if the client is the same?

**backend code**

```
            //Configure Host
            SetConfig(new HostConfig
            {
                DebugMode = false,
                AllowSessionIdsInHttpParams = false,
                UseSecureCookies = true,
                UseSameSiteCookies = true, 
                AllowNonHttpOnlyCookies = true
            });

            // Plugins
            Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature(AppConfig.allowedOrigins, "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS, HEAD", "Content-Type, Authorization, Accept, X-ss-id", true));
```

**frontend**

```
     var instance = axios.create({
        baseURL: Vue.prototype.$AppConfig.URL_API,
        withCredentials: true,
 })
```

Settings
Both backend and frontend is HTTPS.
setting allowedOrigins is set instead of wildcard (*) which gave different issue if I used.

Error:
401 -

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: The answers below directly refer to the code that you had posted. Your subsequent edit removes that code. That edit was made after you received both answers. Hence that edit invalidates or at least leaves them incomplete. This goes against SO's policy on edits. Edits shouldn't invalidate existing answers. Hence the canned comment on Vandalism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to the question, but relates to the question. This is the preferred and best solution to accomplish what I needed to accomplish in the technology stack I am using.

Servicestack backend Config:

```
//Configure option also Host UseSameSiteCookies = true
            SetConfig(new HostConfig
            {
                UseSecureCookies = true
            });

            Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature(AppConfig.allowedOrigins, // configured Origins
                "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS, HEAD", 
                "Content-Type, Authorization, Accept", 
                true)); // allowed Credentials
```

UseSecureCookies must be true, wildcard (*) origins did not work, allowed credentials must be true.

Axios FrontEnd (config instance for Axios)

```
 var instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: Vue.prototype.$AppConfig.URL_API,
    withCredentials: true,
})
```

Using the instance does help to eliminate bowlerplate code, withCredentials can also be set with interceptor, but this code for me is good.

Lastly and for the people like myself who is new to this, don't forget SSL (HTTPS). In IIS you can easily create self sighed certificate for intranet I am sure it's more then enough. You need SSL on both sides, your origins (frontend) and servicestack api (backend.)

Answer (score 2):

> Should the ss-id not be validated against the user agent / client

No, cookies are used to identify a session that given it's a unique id with high entropy is the least predictable identifier sent by HTTP clients. It's not much different to other bearer tokens such as a JWT Tokens or API Keys which authenticates the Bearer as-is, i.e. without additional user agent validation.

Validating against a User-agent would just be security theatre which is common, highly predictable & spoofable, i.e. if they're able to access your Cookie from HTTP Headers they also have access to all other HTTP Headers.

You could validate it against an IP Address but that would break sessions on a network change, e.g. whenever a device roams Wifi points which is why it's typically not done.

To best secure your cookies they should be only sent over SSL as [Secure and HTTP Only](https://blog.dareboost.com/en/2019/03/secure-cookies-secure-httponly-flags/) Cookies (i.e. defaults in [ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net)):

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    UseSecureCookies = true,
    UseHttpOnlyCookies = true,
});
```

For additional protection against CSRF you can enable [SameSite Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite):

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    UseSameSiteCookies = true,
});
```

Although as this can break cross-site functionality and 3rd Party OAuth providers like Twitter OAuth it's set to `Lax` by default.

Comment: I have been struggling to understand this topic.I could not get the cookies to work on my client side (vuejs, axios, javascript) so I ended up using http header X-ss-id, this worked on my dev environment and several clients environment but is started to give me problems on some sites (CORS blocked).So I looked at it again and I decided to use URL out of frustration knowing it is not the best and it also creates allot of additional work for me.Now I will read up on my frontend stack to understand how to send the cookies,I need to upgrade my clients to SSL also.Appreciate your response

Comment: @FrancoisTaljaard I'd focus on getting cookies working, I'm assuming your issue with Ajax cookies is because you haven't specified [credentials:'include'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/credentials), which is [configured in axios with `withCredentials: true`](https://flaviocopes.com/axios-credentials/). What's the reason for not using Add TypeScript Ref + [@servicestack/client](https://docs.servicestack.net/typescript-add-servicestack-reference#typescript-serviceclient)?

Comment: I am using createInstance of Axios and there seemed be have been an issue with that setting, updating the package apparently resolves the issue. The reason I have not looked into TS is because I am the only developer on a very large application, I am flooded with new application requirements and technology requirements, I will one day when I have time or more developers helping me. I am struggle to keep up with the pace of new technology and constantly upgrading. Still on .Net Framework have not moved to Core, hoping ServiceStack will always support my legacy tech.

Comment: @FrancoisTaljaard np, glad it's resolved, though IMO it's much nicer to use [JsonServiceClient in JavaScript](https://docs.servicestack.net/javascript-client). Hopefully when you get new devs they'll help migrate your App over to .NET5/Core where it's much cleaner + faster dev UX with a multitude of simplified deployment options thx to 1st class Linux support. ServiceStack should make it super easy to migrate .NETFX Apps as it uses the same code base with near perfect source-code compatibility, I've migrated tons with very little effort.

Comment: I will post new question as we are moving of the topic of this question, you know stackOverflow keep tabs on us. I  am getting different issues now (error 401 - samesite issue), think its good topic for future users to refer to.